# VideoView in WindowManager not updating

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-windowmanager, window-managers

I'm trying to play a video with VideoView in WindowManager. I'm using the StandOutLibrary for this. I've been pretty successful so far except a couple of things.

MediaController obviously does not work in this case since it needs an activity. So I wrote my custom view to control the videoview. Here is the result-

[image]

Everything works except the seekbar after pausing. After I pause the video and start it again, the seekbar refuses to update. Here's my code to play/pause and update seekbar-

```
 play.setOnClickListener(new Button.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (playing) {
                vv.pause();
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_play);
                playing = !playing;
            } else {
                vv.start();
                play.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_media_pause);
                playing = !playing;
            }
        }
    });

    vv = (VideoView) mView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
    vv.setOnPreparedListener(new OnPreparedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {

            sb.setMax(vv.getDuration());
            sb.postDelayed(onEverySecond, 60);
        }
    });

    vv.setOnCompletionListener(new MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener() {
        public void onCompletion(MediaPlayer mp) {
            close(id);
        }
    });

    sb = (SeekBar) mView.findViewById(R.id.sbar);
    sb.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
        @Override
        public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            vv.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {
            vv.seekTo(sb.getProgress());
        }

        @Override
        public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress,
                boolean fromUser) {
            if (fromUser) {
                vv.seekTo(progress);
                // vv.start();
            }
        }
    });
```

Where is my mistake?

Also the second problem comes after resizing the window. Normally, all the views take the new layout size after resizing the window. I've tried this with a SurfaceView too and it works. But the VideoView does not take the new size. Here is the result after changing the window size-
[image]

Can anyone help me out regarding these two? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You should use `RelativeLayout` as wrapper of your `VideoView`.

**Reference:** [click here](http://blog.kasenlam.com/2012/02/android-how-to-stretch-video-to-fill.html)

Comment: My VideoView is already placed within a RelativeLayout. Do you have any idea how to fix the first problem?